# how to connect to another sql server database(server pc) in local area network

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2005-express

i m creating an application, inwhich client has to acces a database stored in a remote location connnected through a live ip. how can i  connect simply with a database server placed in LAN. both using sql server 2005 express edition. please refer me or help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Set in your connection string IP address of remote server. 
E.g.

```
"Data source=192.168.0.13; Database=MyDb;User ID=my_user;password=12345"
```

where 192.168.0.13 is your remote server IP and MyDb is your database name.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure to configure your SQL Server Express to allow **remote connections**! Those are disabled by default after installation.

Check out the SQL Server Surface Configuration tool (if I'm not mistaken) to configure these settings.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

This not about programming. You have forward the port which Sql Server uses on modem.